# how to show that if $\int_{*}f=\int^{*}f$ then $f$ is measurable and $\int f=\int_{*}f=\int^{*}f$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, measurable-functions

how to show that if $\int_{*}f=\int^{*}f$ then $f$ is measurable and $\int f=\int_{*}f=\int^{*}f$.
I am working with this:

[image: definitions]

well im try like this:

Let $E_{\alpha}=\{x\in X: |f(x)|\leq \alpha\}$ with $\alpha\in [0,\infty]$. I want to show that $E_{\alpha}\in \Sigma$ the sigma algebra in $X$. Im not sure, i need to compare $\alpha$ with the all extended simple function, whatever let $\epsilon>0$ and $L:=\int_{*}f$ then by properties of $\sup$ exist $\psi$ extended simple function such that $L<\int \psi  +\epsilon$, in this moment i believe that i need to compare $\alpha$ with $\psi$ (im not sure)

If $\alpha \geq \psi$ or $\psi\geq \alpha$.

when $\alpha \geq \psi$ and $\psi\leq f$ then $\psi \leq \min\{\alpha,f\}=f$ imply that can separate the set $E_{\alpha}$ right? with measurable sets, but im confuse how to continued, please give me any hint, fot this and the other statement, please, thank you

Well, im try to do like Jose27 said before,

Let $ L=\inf \{\int\phi:\phi\in L^{*}\; extended\; simple, f\leq \phi\; a.e\}$

$ U=\sup \{\int\phi:\phi\in L^{*}\; extended\; simple, \phi\leq f\; a.e\}$

By hypothesis $U=L$ then for $\epsilon>0$ exist $\psi,\phi$ extended simple function such that $\psi-\epsilon<f<\phi+\epsilon$ then by monotony on the integrals we have

$\int \psi-\epsilon<\int f<\int \phi+\epsilon < \infty$
(If $f$ is integrable then f is measurable?)

If i take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ and use $\lim$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ finish the first statement? Thank you

Im still with problem!!

Comment: why put -1 for my excersice? is very easy? no for me, i need help please,

Comment: HInt: Show that we can construct $g,h$ measurable functions such that both $0\leq g\leq f\leq h$, and $\int g= \int h$.

Comment: Thank you Jose27, i will try, in this moment i think that can to choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ and using the bounded integral and upper integral to have  $g_n -\frac{1}{n}\leq  f\leq h_n +\frac{1}{n}$, that is your idea? Thank you again

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of your inequality, but with integrals throughout. The fact that $g_n\leq f\leq h_n$ would be immediate by choosing the functions $g_n, h_n$ from appropriate sets.

Comment: Can i write my attempt and you give me your point of view please?Thank you

Comment: i wrote something above, can you read please Jose27, thank you and excusme please!!

Comment: Your argument is not quite right. First the inequality $\psi-\varepsilon < f< \phi+\varepsilon$ is not the right one; you can only build those functions if you know already that that $f$ is bounded and measurable. Also notice that we can't just integrate the above inequality, since we don't know that $X$ has finite measure. Rather you want to work with the definition of upper and lower integral to construct $g_n$ and $h_n$ such that $$\int h_nd\mu-1/n \leq \int^* fd\mu=\int_* fd\mu\leq \int g_nd\mu +1/n.$$ Notice that, by definition we would have $g_n\leq f \leq h_n$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: thank you again, but i not think so, because how to say that $f$ is measurable?                  if $g_n\leq f\leq \ h_n$ then $E_{\alpha}= \{x\in X:g_n\leq -\alpha\leq f\}$ $\cup$ $\{x\in X: -\alpha\leq g_n\leq f\}$ $\cup\ldots$, that is? in the inequality above can i take the limit? Thank you Jose27

Comment: I'm not sure what the $E_\alpha$ is supposed to get you? You can take the limit, the problem is that, as is, there is no limit function for the $g_n$ or $h_h$. You'll have to tweak these a bit to guarantee that they have a limit. The measurability of $f$ will be a consequence of the fact that it's equal a.e. to a measurable function $g$ as in my first comment (here we will need the  measure to be compete).

Comment: thank you Jose27, i undesrtand the last part that you said, i will think about that, thank you